# How to build React application with Vite to be able to run the app without web server? Just double click on index.html file and that's it?

Tags: reactjs, server, build, vite

It is doable with Create React App but with Vite ...

I try to add relative paths but still get error for CORS policy.
I add "homepage": "." in package.json file but still not working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this using a single file build plugin called `viteSingleFile`.
Just add it to the plugins in `vite.config.js|ts` file:

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), viteSingleFile()]
})
```

Comment: what? viteSingleFile is not available